# hereinafter/henceforward * refers to?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, writing

Can I say these? Which is to be preferred? or have you got any other suggestion?

> Hereinafter client refers to a smartphone using Android.
>
> Henceforward client refers to a smartphone using Android.

My intended meaning is that when I say "client" I mean an Android smartphone.

Earlier in the text I describe different kinds of possible clients, but since my report only focuses on android phones I want to be able to write "client" and have the reader understand the meaning of 'client' as 'Android phone'.

Comment: Note that the word *client* should be marked with either quotation marks or italics.

Comment: I thought these words are rather outdated at this point, but neither answer mentions this. Are they archaic, or simply "fancy"?

Comment: @KenB They are legalese: They are still used, but in a specific context. It is like _persons_: You normally don't hear "there are 5 persons."

Comment: I've never even heard "hereinafter" before, though "hereafter" is a similar word that I'm quite familiar with. I'd assume they have similar meaning? But I've honestly never heard it before. With "henceforward" I don't think I've heard that either, but "henceforth" I've heard often enough. Other answers mention legalese, which sounds reasonable, but I think "hereafter" and "henceforth" are probably more common (though still not very common in their own rights).

Comment: @WendiKidd: *Hereinafter* is not quite the same as *hereafter*. *Hereinafter* means "in the remainder of this document"; *hereafter* as an adverb means "after this", and as a noun usually means roughly "afterlife". So they're close, but they're not always interchangeable. But yes, *henceforward* and *henceforth* are synonymous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way perhaps is to say:

> From this point (forward/onwards) "client" refers to a smartphone
>   using Android.

The formality is retained without the fancy-pantsy wording which may trip non-native English speakers up.

Comment: Even native speakers may trip over words like *hereinafter*--depending on how fancy their pants are, of course.

Comment: Indeed. It is tragic, but when I was in school (I'm 21, so I left 5-ish years ago) many people struggled with English class. Such a shame, that people fail to fully conquer their native language. I personally think they were lazy. :)

Comment: Thanks, it's hard for a non native speaker to know the level of fanciness of a word, or if it's too much, since natively we use more formal (but not overly ofcource) language in academic writing.

Answer (score 10):

*Hereinafter* and *henceforward* are best avoided unless you are writing a formal legal text. If you are, then you should take legal advice. Otherwise, you can just say something like:

> In the rest of this text I use the word ‘client’ to refer to a
>   smartphone using Android.