# Is the phrase "in manner hereinafter mentioned" okay to be used?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have a question regarding to formal phrase **"in manner hereinafter mentioned"**.

I need to make a remark in the end of the sentence that the detailed information regarding that question is elsewhere in the document. Though I cannot point the precise clause of the document because it has no determination.

So I want to use a phrase that say to a document reader that there is the detailed information herein but the reader need to look for it by themselves.

Is the phrase **"in manner hereinafter mentioned"** good for the official document context?

For example here is the sentence:

> When your work with the system is done, make sure to disconnect the
>   cables and turn off the system (in manner hereinafter mentioned).

I will be grateful for any assistance!

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/hereinafter-henceforward-refers-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context (an instructional manual) does not justify that degree of formality. You want to say "as described below".

But if you were writing a legal contract,  something like it might be used. However, an article is required:

... in **the** manner set forth below.

or simply

... as set forth below.

The word **hereinafter** means "*henceforward* in this document", so it does not mean "as described below". Here is how it is used:

> Gamilato (hereinafter "Questioner") ...

It means that when the word **Questioner** is encountered later in the document, it refers to "Gamilato".

Comment: Okay, so this phrase is really the chancellery from jurisprudence field? 
And you're right, the context is more like instructional manual.
But doesn't the phrase *as described below* point that the detailed info is just below that particular sentence and not elsewhere in the document?

Comment: The jungles of jurisprudence are *hereinafter*'s usual habitat, but the word could appear in a work of scholarship as well.  **below** could mean later in the chapter. It does not necessarily mean "immediately below".

Comment: May I say *as described herein below*. Does it sound okay? I mean, from my point of view, seems that **herein** makes wider the sense of **below**.

Comment: No, that is not good.  **herein** is another word that's too formal for your context for one thing, and for another, **below** alone would suffice.  **herein** means something like "in multiple places in this text" or "throughout this text".

Comment: I see! Thank you so much for your help. I wish I had that intuitive feel for the English like you.

Comment: It helps to be born to English-speaking parents in an English-speaking country and to have spent decades reading books written in English. :)   My best advice would be to work from and emulate examples in your field, written in English, although many instructional manuals are very poorly written and poorly edited.

Comment: Yes, you've got that ☺ Thank you! Reading proper literature and style guides is helping, but there is always the cases like that.. Thank God, there is this site with nice intelligent people as you!